# Page number resets when new section starts - MigraDoc

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using MigraDoc to create a PDF. As per my requirement, I have to add different headers according to the contents of the page\section. I am able to achieve it by adding new section and defining new header for every section. Till here, it works fine.
In footer, I am showing page numbers using "AddPageField". But I realized that whenever a new section starts, page field reset to 1. Is there any way that footer continues the page count across all sections?
If I use only one section throughout the document, then page number continues. But in this case, I can not use different headers.

Comment: I updated my answer. Took me pretty long to understand what's going on, but finally I found the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

<s>This appears to be a bug in MigraDoc up to version 1.50 beta 1.</s>

The bug wasn't fixed yet, but it should require a small modification only and I hope it will be corrected with the next release.

I had to change my mind: it is not a bug, it is a feature.

To achieve what the OP wants you have to assign a `PageSetup` to the first section that sets the StartingNumber and also assign a `PageSetup` to the second section that does not set the StartingNumber.

If no `PageSetup` is set for the second section then this section will inherit the `PageSetup` from the first section and the StartingNumber will be applied to both sections. This is the desired behaviour if each section is e.g. a serial letter.

Here is my testcode (just a code snippet):

```
var sec1 = document.LastSection; 
sec1.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone(); 
sec1.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 17; 

sec1.Footers.Primary = new HeaderFooter(); 
var para = sec1.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph(); 
para.AddPageField(); 

var sec2 = document.AddSection(); 
sec2.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
```

The second section inherits the footer from the first section, but a new `PageSetup` overrides the StartingNumber.

The `Clone()` comes handy here.