# Always same page number in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc, page-numbering

With this code I always get the same page number on every page. How to solve this problem?

```
    static void DefineContentSection(Document document)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = true;
        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.AddText("Page ");
        paragraph.AddPageField();
        paragraph.AddText(" of ");
        paragraph.AddNumPagesField();

        section.Footers.Primary.Add(paragraph);
        section.Footers.EvenPage.Add(paragraph.Clone());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that code, every section will start with page number 1. If all sections only have a single page, all pages will have #1. Create sections with more than just one page to also see #2 etc.

Remove `section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;` to get a document with consecutive page numbers.

Maybe this answer is helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30206884/162529